Multiple errors with tabularray
I want to create a table with the tabularray package but I don't understand why the compilation gives me several errors: I have the impression that it is due to word wrapping in the cells.
Can anyone help me?
My code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs,counter,diagbox,siunitx,varwidth}
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824
\usepackage{textgreek}
\chemsetup{greek=textgreek}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]%
\begin{tblr}{
vspan=even,
colspec = {X[2,c]X[1.5,c]X[1.5,c]X[c]X[c]||X[c]X[c]},
cell{X-Z}{2-6}={font=\small},
row{1}={font=\bfseries},
}
       \toprule[blue]
ions en présence & \ch{H3O\pch{}} & \ch{CH3COOH} & \ch{HO\mch{}\lqd{}} & \ch{A\mch{}\aq{}} & \ch{Na\pch{}\aq{}} & \ch{Cl\mch{}\aq{}}\\
       \midrule[blue]
        $V=0$   & $n_a=C_a V_a$&  $n_b=C_b V$& excès    & 0& $C_a V_a$&\\
      $V<V_{eq1}$& ${C_a V_a -C_b V\\=C_b (V_{eq}-V)}$  &  $\approx 0$& excès       & $C_b V$   &   $C_b V_{eq}$    &\\
            $V=V_{eq1}$& $\approx 0$& ${C_b V -C_a V_a\\=C_b(V-V_{eq})}$    & excès     &   $C_b V$ &   $C_b V_{eq}$    &\\
            $V_{eq1}<V<V_{eq2}$ & $\approx 0$& ${C_b V -C_a V_a\\=C_b(V-V_{eq})}$   & excès     &   $C_b V$ &   $C_b V_{eq}$    &\\
            $V=V_{eq2}$& $\approx 0$& ${C_b V -C_a V_a\\=C_b(V-V_{eq})}$    & excès     &   $C_b V$ &   $C_b V_{eq}$    &\\
            $V>V_{eq2}$& $\approx 0$& ${C_b V -C_a V_a\\=C_b(V-V_{eq})}$    & excès     &   $C_b V$ &   $C_b V_{eq}$    &\\
        \bottomrule[blue]
\end{tblr}
    \caption{Tableau d'avancement pour le dosage d'un acide fort (acide chlorhydrique) par une base forte (soude)}
    \label{tab:tableau_avancement_dosage_acidefort_baseforte}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Errors comes from \ in math mode. You could use \begin{aligned}...\end{aligned} instead. By the way you should use mode=math for cell displayed in inline math mode.

Off-topic: The option list left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm may be expressed more succinctly as margin = 1.5cm.

You cannot have \\ in a cell, unless protected inside something else.
I'd use gathered (but hidden for simplicity of input in a command).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs,counter,diagbox,siunitx,varwidth}
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824
\usepackage{textgreek}
\chemsetup{greek=textgreek}

\newcommand{\longeq}[1]{\begin{gathered}#1\end{gathered}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\begin{tblr}{
  vspan=even,
  colspec = {ccccc||cc},
  cell{X-Z}{2-6}={font=\small},
  row{1}={font=\bfseries},
}
\toprule[blue]
ions en présence &
\ch{H3O\pch{}} &
\ch{CH3COOH} &
\ch{HO\mch{}\lqd{}} &
\ch{A\mch{}\aq{}} &
\ch{Na\pch{}\aq{}} &
\ch{Cl\mch{}\aq{}} \\
\midrule[blue]
$V=0$       & $n_a=C_a V_a$ & $n_b=C_b V$ & excès & 0& $C_a V_a$ \\
$V<V_{eq1}$ & $\longeq{C_a V_a -C_b V\\=C_b (V_{eq}-V)}$ & $\approx 0$ & excès       & $C_b V$   &   $C_b V_{eq}$    &\\
$V=V_{eq1}$ & $\approx 0$ & $\longeq{C_b V -C_a V_a\\=C_b(V-V_{eq})}$    & excès     &   $C_b V$ &   $C_b V_{eq}$    &\\
$V_{eq1}<V<V_{eq2}$ & $\approx 0$& $\longeq{C_b V -C_a V_a\\=C_b(V-V_{eq})}$   & excès     &   $C_b V$ &   $C_b V_{eq}$    &\\
$V=V_{eq2}$& $\approx 0$& $\longeq{C_b V -C_a V_a\\=C_b(V-V_{eq})}$    & excès     &   $C_b V$ &   $C_b V_{eq}$    &\\
$V>V_{eq2}$& $\approx 0$& $\longeq{C_b V -C_a V_a\\=C_b(V-V_{eq})}$    & excès     &   $C_b V$ &   $C_b V_{eq}$    &\\
\bottomrule[blue]
\end{tblr}
    \caption{Tableau d'avancement pour le dosage d'un acide fort (acide chlorhydrique) par une base forte (soude)}
    \label{tab:tableau_avancement_dosage_acidefort_baseforte}
\end{table}

\end{document}

I changed the colspec to avoid complications (your columns become wider than the text width).

